# How can I replace multiple strings within a string without overlapping results?

Tags: php, regex, replace, preg-replace, str-replace

I'm trying to create common masks from a string like so:

```
012abc.d+e_fg~hijk => 012{start}.d+{middle}_fg~{end}jk
```

replace:

```
$arrFromTo = array(
              'st' => '{pre}',
              'abc' => '{start}',
              'e' => '{middle}',
              'hi' => '{end}',
              'dd' => '{post}'
             );
```

Instead I keep overlapping replacements and get something like this instead (using a loop of `str_replace`'s):

```
012{{pre}art}.d+{mi{post}le}_fg~{end}jk
```

Because the `st` is found in the already replaced `{start}` and `dd` is found in `{middle}`.

How would you replace the following?

```
$str = 'abc.d+e_fg~hijk';

echo replace_vars($str); // Desired output: 012{start}.d+{middle}_fg~{end}kJ
```

Comment: I was thinking rearrange the array so `'dd' => '{post}'` was in a different position, but that raised other issues.

Comment: It's not often I suggest regex, but in this case it might be prudent so you perform lookahead/behinds to check for what you are expecting before you replace

Comment: @scrowler Unfortunately there's a bug in my PCRE library with variable length negative look behinds. I'm unable to upgrade PCRE library so I stopped going down that path at this point.

Comment: The issue you'll have with regular expressions is that php doesn't support variable-length negative lookbehinds. If it did, you could use a regular expression like: `/(?<!{\w*)(e)(?!\w*})/i`  This would mean give me any "e" where it is not between curly braces and any other word character. The \w* makes it a variable-length lookahead/behind. Apparently pcre handles the variable-length lookahead well, but not the lookbehind.

Comment: You could use a state machine. As you loop through the string, keep a list of the last `n` characters that match the first `n` characters of something in your replace list. Once you have a full match, replace the last `n` characters with your replacement string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I might misunderstand, but you don't seem to need regex for the replacing. They're simple, literal replacements.

```
$from = '012abc.d+e_fg~hijk';
$arrFromTo = array(
              'st' => '{pre}',
              'abc' => '{start}',
              'e' => '{middle}',
              'hi' => '{end}',
              'dd' => '{post}'
             );
$to = strtr($from, $arrFromTo); // 012{start}.d+{middle}_fg~{end}jk
```

`strtr()` is awesome. It takes a very readable input and it doesn't re-replace like your problem in the loop.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `preg_replace` like this:

```
$str = '012abc.d+e_fg~hijk';
$arrFromTo = array(
              'st' => '{pre}',
              'abc' => '{start}',
              'e' => '{middle}',
              'hi' => '{end}',
              'dd' => '{post}'
             );

$reArr=array();
foreach($arrFromTo as $k=>$v){
   $reArr['/' . $k . '(?![^{}]*})/'] = $v;
}

echo preg_replace(array_keys($reArr), array_values($reArr), $str);
//=> 012{start}.d+{middle}_fg~{end}jk
```

Core of this regex is this negative lookaead: `(?![^{}]*})`

Which avoid matching keys of array if it is enclosed in `{...}` since all the replacements are enclosed in `{...}`.

Comment: Why `preg_replace`? Why not `str_replace` or `strtr`? No regexing necessary, is there?

Comment: How can you use a lookahead in `str_replace`?

Comment: Why do you need lookahead?? They're literal replacements... There are no `{` and `}` in the source string.

Comment: `str_replace` takes arrays too, isn't that smart enough not to re-replace? Maybe not, dunno

Comment: Yes I know it takes an array but `echo str_replace(array_keys($arrFromTo), array_values($reArr), $str);` prints `12{start}.d+{mi{post}le}_fg~{end}jk`

Comment: Oh, okay, so `str_replace` isn't as smart as `strtr`. Too bad. Now we know!

Comment: Yes right but still you were quite right about `strtr` +1 to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

This will search the string for each replacement in order. If it finds one, it will split the string, and search the remainder of the string for any other replacements.

```
$str = '012abc.d+e_fg~hijk';

$rep = array(
    'st' => '{pre}',
    'abc' => '{start}',
    'e' => '{middle}',
    'hi' => '{end}',
    'dd' => '{post}'
);

$searched = '';

foreach ($rep as $key => $r) {
    if (strpos($str, $key) !== false) {

        $searched .= substr($str, 0, strpos($str, $key)) . $r;
        $str = substr($str, strpos($str, $key) + strlen($key));

    }
}

$searched .= $str;

echo $searched; //012{start}.d+{middle}_fg~{end}jk
```

It will search and find them in the order that you have specified.